# JavaFX on WSL - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

Tags: openjdk, windows-subsystem-for-linux, javafx

I'm following [this guide](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx) on openjfx.io to compile and run [HelloFX.java](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/blob/master/HelloFX/Maven/hellofx/src/main/java/HelloFX.java).

- Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, via Windows Sybsystem For Linux
- Installed openjdk via `apt install openjdk-11-jre`
- Downloaded JavaFX from [here](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/), linked from the guide.

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.5" 2019-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.5+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.118.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.5+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.118.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

---

Here's what I get:

```
$ export PATH_TO_FX=/home/connor/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib
$ javac --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.controls HelloFX.java
$ java HelloFX
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloFX
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

I think it's an error in my JFX setup; an error in the XMing setup would cause a different error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always troublesome with JavaFX. ;) I recommend you using the JDK Amazon Corretto 8: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-8-ug/downloads-list.html

It works fine and I never had any issues with it.

Comment: Does it, like, come with JFX built-in?

Comment: Of course, otherwise I wouldn't recommend it to you. ;)

Comment: @SIGSTACKFAULT if it worked consider accepting my answer.

Comment: It broke my eclipse ("Launch error" with no more details provided). I followed the instructions and thought I knew what I was doing. Tried several things etc, no luck. Probably not your fault so I won't downvote, but had to vent my frustration somewhere.

Comment: I had the same problem as the OP an this answer worked beautifully to me.
@EroStefano, THANK YOU SO MUCH.